# What is the phrase for "weakness in courses"?

Tags: phrases

I am describing my students and want to say they do not know much about the courses that they passed last year.

How can I say it in English?

E.g. My students **are weak in science**, so I can't teach them advanced materials.

Comment: Please elaborate on the context.

Comment: "They do not know much about the courses that they passed last year."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To emphasize, perhaps more diplomatically, the idea that the fault lies with prior courses (i.e., Teachers and/or the Students' [retention] abilities), I’d try to work in the notion of “[prerequisite knowledge and skills](http://ualr.edu/pace/udcd/prereq.html)” and the lack thereof.

For example:
"The Students lack the prerequisite knowledge and skills (=the basic knowledge required=the fundamentals) to advance to and succeed at the next level (of the study of [whatever subject]."

> Prerequisite [...] that must exist or happen before something else can
>   happen or be done [Example] [prerequisite
>   knowledge](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/prerequisite_1)

(from Oxford Learner’s Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

There could be many ways to express this idea, depending on the context and style.

Consider some formal examples suitable for a report, perhaps:

> "The students' proficiency in X is limited."
>
> "The students' knowledge of X is inadequate to proceed to advanced topics."

Or you can simply (and informally) say, **"They don't know enough of the last year's course material."**

Answer (score 1):

Consider,

> *My students have some [considerable] **knowledge gaps** (or **shortcomings**) in science, so I can't
>   teach them advanced materials.*
>
> gap: an incomplete or deficient area: *a gap in her knowledge*
>   [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gap)
>
> shortcoming: a failing or **deficiency**; "that interpretation is an
>   unfortunate defect of our lack of information" [Princeton University, Farlex Inc.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shortcoming)

Answer (score 1):

You can try these words.

1. Nonconservant.
2. Philistine.
3. Illiterati.

These can be used to describe the people who are not well-informed in particular subject.